# Relay Tester Box with BlinkM

Tags: arduino, blinkm, relay

I'm trying to create something similar to [this project](http://hackaday.com/2009/01/10/wireless-blinkm-control/) and was looking for something cheap to use in place of the Relay Tester Box....
The project used an old relay tester box to control a colour LED set. The box has four or more potentiometers and some switches which were used as input devices for an arduino.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This needs more explaining here. If the link dies the question becomes totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the relay tester is a glorified set of potentiometers, with a switch or two; the inputs to the Arduino appear to all be analog lines, so you should be able to craft your own, and give it a funky patina of age as you see fit. :-)  The schematic of the original relay tester is even included in the author's original post, so designing something similar or identical to the original would be pretty straightforward.